# Programmatically moving the mouse

Tags: vb.net

A bit odd maybe, but how can I move the cursor using code in vb.net? I can't seem to find the proper method.

This is in vb.net

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You may use:

```
Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = New Point(x, y)
```

Comment: +1. We can use `myControl.PointToScreen(New Point(0, 0))` to get the location of a control in screen coordinates